# org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method <init>()V not found in mvn java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, snakeyaml, snyk

I am getting this error after updating my pom dependency.

from snakeyaml 1.3 >>>>> snakeyaml 2.0
and
spring-boot to 2.7.10

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class  nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.createYaml(YamlProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.getObject(YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.java:115) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at 
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:463) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-boot 2.7.10 Isn’t the spring that manages dependencies 5.3.26? Why is your spring-beans here 5.3.20? This compatibility fix occurs in 5.3.26, you need to upgrade the dependency to 5.3.26 or above

[gh-30097](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30097)